# Mathematical model alignment in the alignat environment

Tags: math-mode, equations, alignat

I really can't figure out how this alignat environment works, I am trying to align at least the part where I wrote the indices. I checked the questions but nothing seems to work. I want to align the equations along the green line in two different alignat environment. Thank you. T

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts, empheq,mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\textbf{\textit{Subject to;}} 
\begin{alignat}{2}
\nonumber\\
&f^r(x)= P^r_{loss} + Q_{loss}^r  & &   \forall r \in R\\[1mm]
&h_1^r:=\begin{cases}
|V|_{lower} - |V_i^r|\textrm{, } & |V_i^r| \leq |V|_{lower}\\[-1mm]
|V_i^r|-|V|_{upper}\textrm{, } & |V_i^r|\geq|V|_{upper}  \\[-1mm]
\hfill 0 \textrm{, } & |V|_{lower} \geq |V_i^r|  \leq |V|_{upper}\\
\end{cases}  & &  \forall i \in N \textrm{ , } \forall r \in R \\[1mm]
&h_2^r:=\begin{cases}
\omega_{lower} - \omega_r \textrm{, } & \omega_r \leq \omega_{lower}\\[-1mm]
\omega_r-\omega_{upper}\textrm{, } & \omega_r \geq \omega_{upper}  \\[-1mm]
\hfill 0 \textrm{, } & \omega_{lower} \geq \omega_r \leq \omega_{upper}\\
\end{cases}  & &   \forall r \in R \\[2mm]
&h_3^r:=\begin{cases}
I_{lower} - I_{ij}\textrm{, } & I_{ij} \leq I_{lower}\\[-1mm]
I_{ij}-I_{upper}\textrm{, } & I_{ij}\geq I_{upper}  \\[-1mm]
\hfill 0 \textrm{, } & I_{lower} \geq I_{ij}  \leq I_{upper}\\
\end{cases}  & &  \forall i,j \in R \\[1mm]
&x= \left\{ m_{p_i} \dots m_{p_{|B|}}, n_{q_i} \dots n_{q_{|B|}} \right\}  & & \forall i \in B
\end{alignat}

\begin{alignat}{2}
&\min_{x\in \mathcal{R}^n}  \hat{\mathcal{L}}(x) = \sum_{r\in R} \dfrac{\mathcal{L}^r(x)}{|R|}  & &\forall r \in R\\
&\mathcal{L}^r(x) := \begin{cases}
\hat{h}^r(x) := h^r_{max}(x) \textrm{, } &  h_{max}^r > 0\\
\hat{f}^r(x):= \arctan\left[ f^r(x)\right] - \dfrac{\pi}{2}\textrm{, } & h_{max}^r \leq 0 
\end{cases} & & \forall r \in R\\
&h_{max}^r = \max\left(h_1^r,h_2^r,h_3^r\right)  && \forall r \in R 
\end{alignat}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What you want to align is not very clear to me. Could you explain more, or post a sketch of what you'd like to have?

Comment: The problem is I have two different alignat environment and as can be seen in the picture, the indices are not aligned and the equations do not start at the same point in the left.

Comment: What do you want to align, exactly, on the left side? The beginning of each line or the `=` signs?

Comment: The beginning of each line, I have edited the question and add the line to the picture that describes what I want to do.

Comment: @AbdurrahmanYavuz Why should you have two `alignat` environments if you want to preserve the alignment?

Comment: There will be text between them.

Comment: You can use `\intertext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single `alignat` environment and use `\intertext` if you want to set text between the two parts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
\makebox[1em][l]{\bfseries\itshape Subject to} & &\quad& \nonumber\\
&f^r(x)= P^r_{\mathrm{loss}} + Q_{\mathrm{loss}}^r  &&   \forall r \in R\\[1ex]
&h_1^r:=\begin{cases}
  |V|_{\mathrm{lower}} - |V_i^r|, & |V_i^r| \leq |V|_{\mathrm{lower}}\\
  |V_i^r|-|V|_{\mathrm{upper}},   & |V_i^r|\geq|V|_{\mathrm{upper}}  \\
  0,              & |V|_{\mathrm{lower}} \geq |V_i^r|  \leq |V|_{\mathrm{upper}}
\end{cases}  & &  \forall i \in N,\ \forall r \in R \\[1ex]
&h_2^r:=\begin{cases}
  \omega_{\mathrm{lower}} - \omega_r ,        & \omega_r \leq \omega_{\mathrm{lower}}\\
  \omega_r-\omega_{\mathrm{upper}}\textrm{, } & \omega_r \geq \omega_{\mathrm{upper}}  \\
  0 ,        & \omega_{\mathrm{lower}} \geq \omega_r \leq \omega_{\mathrm{upper}}
\end{cases}  & &   \forall r \in R \\[1ex]
&h_3^r:=\begin{cases}
  I_{\mathrm{lower}} - I_{ij}, & I_{ij} \leq I_{\mathrm{lower}}\\
  I_{ij}-I_{\mathrm{upper}},   & I_{ij}\geq I_{\mathrm{upper}}  \\
  0,           & I_{\mathrm{lower}} \geq I_{ij}  \leq I_{\mathrm{upper}}
\end{cases}  & &  \forall i,j \in R \\[1ex]
&x= \{ m_{p_i} \dots m_{p_{|B|}}, n_{q_i} \dots n_{q_{|B|}} \}  & & \forall i \in B \\
\intertext{Here we can add text to comment and divide the two parts;
this text can also wrap across lines}
&\!\min_{x\in \mathcal{R}^n}\hat{\mathcal{L}}(x) =
   \sum_{r\in R} \dfrac{\mathcal{L}^r(x)}{|R|}  & &\forall r \in R \\[1ex]
&\mathcal{L}^r(x) := \begin{cases}
  \hat{h}^r(x) := h^r_{\mathrm{max}}(x), &  h_{\mathrm{max}}^r > 0 \\[1ex]
  \hat{f}^r(x):= \arctan[f^r(x)] - \frac{\pi}{2}, & h_{\mathrm{max}}^r \leq 0 
\end{cases} & & \forall r \in R \\[1ex]
&h_{\mathrm{max}}^r = \max(h_1^r,h_2^r,h_3^r)  && \forall r \in R 
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

I've made several small changes; please, review them, because they're in line with common practices.

[image]

Comment: This works properly, thank you. It is worth noting that 'flalign' could also be a solution, I guess. I will be working with 3rd party template, I hope \intertext inherits the format of the normal text that is used in the template.